# QGIS saga supervised classification

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, classification, saga, land-use

I'm using QGIS 3.0 with the expanded SAGA options. I created a training file in SAGA standalone that I am using, but would prefer the GRASS kappa comparasion options. I have already performed the classifications in SAGA standalone but want to use qgis. 
I'm just a little confused about if I'm going to perform the classification and select every band individually and if that will give me 6 outputs. It's a landsat 8 image, 30 km by 50km. 
If anyone knows of additional documention, tutorials about the saga toolbox within QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

NASA runs online courses that use QGIS to classify Landsat imagery. Perhaps you can find some support there.
[Advanced Webinar: Land Cover Classification with Satellite Imagery](https://arset.gsfc.nasa.gov/land/webinars/advanced-land-classification)